# how to replace with %2B in servlet request get

Tags: java, servlets

How to replace + with %2b, some searches are taking + as space, i am unable to do in java servlets

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.replaceEach(str, new String[]{"+", "=", ...}, new String[]{"%2b", "%3D", ...})
```

Comment: In which version is the StringEscapeUtils class is?

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.net.URLEncoder`

For example: with `URLEncoder.encode( "one+two space", "UTF-8" )` you'll get string `one%2Btwo+space`